# How to decrypt an AES-256 encrypted zip file using Crypto API

Tags: delphi, zip, aes, cryptoapi

I am attempting to decompression AES-256 encrypted files in Delphi using `TZipFile` and Microsoft Crypto. It always returns a bad data error and returns gibberish.

**Background...**

I am using the standard `TZipFile` class to open the zip, and have registered my compression handler as follows:

```pascal
const zcAESEncrypted = 99;
RegisterCompressionHandler( TZipCompression(zcAESEncrypted), nil, DecompressStream );
```

Which uses the following method:

```pascal
function DecompressStream(InStream: TStream; const ZipFile: TZipFile; const Item: TZipHeader): TStream;
var
  LStream : TStream;
  isEncrypted: Boolean;
begin
  isEncrypted := (Item.Flag and 1) = 1;

  if isEncrypted and (ZipFile is TEncryptedZipFile) and ( Item.CompressionMethod = zcAESEncrypted ) then
    LStream := AESDecryptStream(InStream, TEncryptedZipFile(ZipFile).Password, Item.CompressedSize )
  else
    LStream := InStream;
  Result := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LStream, -15, LStream <> InStream);
end;
```

The code for the AES decryption is as follows:

```pascal
function AESDecryptStream(InStream: TStream; const Password: string; FileSize: Integer): TStream;
const
  AES_KEY_SIZE   = 16 ;
  IN_CHUNK_SIZE  = AES_KEY_SIZE * 10; // a buffer must be a multiple of the key size
var
  chunkSize: Integer;
  hProv: HCRYPTPROV;
  hHash: HCRYPTHASH;
  hKey: HCRYPTKEY;
  lpBuffer: PByte;
  len, keySize: Int64;
  fsOut : TFileStream;
  keyStr: WideString;
  isFinal: BOOL;
  outLen: Integer;
  readTotalSize: Integer;
begin
  keyStr := WideString(Password);
  len := lstrlenW( PWideChar( keyStr ));
  keySize := len * sizeof(WideChar); // size in bytes

  // Acquire a CryptoAPI context
  if not CryptAcquireContext(@hProv, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  // Create a hash object
  if not CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, @hHash) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  // Hash the encrypted data
  if not CryptHashData(hHash, @keyStr, keySize, 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  // Create a key object from the password
  if not CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0, @hKey) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  Result := TMemoryStream.Create();
  fsOut := TFileStream.Create( 'C:\Temp\Stream_Out.txt', fmCreate); // For debugging only

  lpBuffer := AllocMem(IN_CHUNK_SIZE);
  isFinal := FALSE;
  readTotalSize := 0;

  while isFinal = False do
  begin
    chunkSize := imin( IN_CHUNK_SIZE, FileSize - readTotalSize );

    outLen := InStream.ReadData( lpBuffer, chunkSize );
    if outLen = 0 then
       break;

    readTotalSize := readTotalSize + outLen;
    if readTotalSize >= FileSize then
      isFinal := TRUE;

    if not CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, isFinal, 0, lpBuffer, @outLen) then
      RaiseLastOSError;    // Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOSError with message 'System Error.  Code: -2146893819. Bad Data.'

    fsOut.Write( lpBuffer, outLen);
    Result.Write( lpBuffer, outLen );
  end;

  FreeMem( lpBuffer );
  fsOut.Free;

  // Release the hash object
  CryptDestroyHash(hHash);

  // Release the key object
  CryptDestroyKey(hKey);

  // Release the CryptoAPI context
  CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
end;
```

This code is based on:

https://gist.github.com/hasherezade/2860d94910c5c5fb776edadf57f0bef6

Which, while it seems a bit dubious, was the only example I could find and does claim to work (with AES-128).

However, the code raises an error on the `CryptDecrypt()` function:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOSError with message 'System Error.  Code: -2146893819. Bad Data.'

Based on the requirements laid out in the Winzip documentation:

https://www.winzip.com/en/support/aes-encryption/

There are some obvious failings:

- It lacks a salt value (16 bytes for AES-256), which I take to be the first 16 bytes of the file
- It does not perform 1000 iterations of the key generation

However, I cannot see how these changes should be implemented using the Crypto API. Potentially, this is not even possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For AES-256, `AES_KEY_SIZE` needs to be 32. The code you linked to is using AES-128, which uses a key size of 16.

Also, your call to `CryptHashData()`  is wrong. You need to drop the `@` and use a `PWideChar` cast instead:

`CryptHashData(hHash, PWideChar(keyStr), keySize, 0);`

---

Also, not an error, but you really should be using `UnicodeString` instead of `WideString`. And since `string` is `UnicodeString`, you don't need the `keyStr` variable at all, just use the `Password` as-is:

`CryptHashData(hHash, PWideChar(Password), ByteLength(Password), 0);`

Comment: Thanks Remy, it is expecting a pbByte/pointer there, so I changed the call to: CryptHashData(hHash, PByte(PWideChar(keyStr)), ByteLength(keyStr), 0). Unfortunately it still returns the "Bad Data" error on the very final call to CryptDecrypt(). (Possibly, I'm truncating the data). At any rate, I think the other ways the code fails to meet the standard mean that I am heading down the wrong route with this

Comment: "*Unfortunately it still returns the "Bad Data" error on the very final call to `CryptDecrypt()`*" - do you mean only when `isFinal=true`? Have you tried padding the `outLen` to `IN_CHUNK_SIZE` on the final chunk? Or, does `CryptDecrypt()` fail *every time* regardless of `isFinal`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should have pointed out that the error always occurs when isFinal = true. It occurs even if I set outLen to IN_CHUNK_SIZE or reset lpBuffer to be the size of outLen.
However, I appear to be making a fundamental error. Why does my write code above create a file (fsOut) of size readTotalSize but containing only a repeating of the same 320 bytes (i.e. IN_CHUNK_SIZE). This occurs even if I comment out the CryptDecrypt() line (where I would expect to to be saving the TStream content directly to file).

Comment: @nix `TStream.Write()` does not have an overload that accepts a pointer. So, you are not writing the contents of the byte array that `lpBuffer` points at, you are writing the contents of the call stack where `lpBuffer` itself is located. You need to either 1) dereference the pointer when passing it to `Write()`, or else 2) use `WriteData()` instead, which does accept a pointer (and matches your use of `ReadData()`)

Comment: Ah yes, of course. You're right.

Comment: Are you aware of anyone successfully using TZipFile to decrypt an AES encrypted zip? I can find no examples of it, though Embarcadero hints at it: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Extract

Comment: @nix no, but then again, I don't use `TZipFile` myself. I use ZipForge instead, which has built-in support for encrypting/decrypting zips.